# how to use active directory with windows authentication asp.net?

Tags: c#

I have to check if a user is part of a GroupC in active directory. If it is I should be able to access without prompting for username and password and if not it should redirect me to a specific page. I tried like this.

```
if (User.IsInRole(@"domain\GroupA\GroupB\groupC") || User.IsInRole(@"domain\GroupA\GroupB\ADMIN")) 
{    
     Response.Write("hello user:");
     Response.Write(User.Identity.Name);
}
else
{ 
     Response.Redirect("~/Contacts.aspx");             
}
```

In my web.config I have this:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
       <authorization>
         <allow roles="domain\GroupA\GroupB\GroupC"></allow>
          <allow roles="domain\GroupA\GroupB\ADMIN"></allow>
         <allow users="domain\Aplikacionet"></allow>
         <deny users="*"/>
       </authorization>
```

Application in production prompts a login form and is not allowing to access the application. Any help please?

Comment: Have you enabled Windows authentication in the IIS web application?

Comment: Why do you want to check the role in this way `User.IsInRole(@"domain\GroupA\GroupB\groupC")`?. If you want to check the user exist in GroupC then it should be simply like this `User.IsInRole("GroupC")`

Comment: Yes, Windows authentication is enables on IIS but still is not working.